# Arrays not working correctly with functions in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am creating a program for a college workshop. I am almost done, but when I compiled my program and ran it, it did not work the way it is supposed to:
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calulation(long long int barcode[100], double price[100], int quantity[100], int i);

int main(void) {
    long long int barcode[100];
    double price[100];
    int quantity[100];
    int i;

    printf("Grocery Store Inventory \n");
    printf("======================= \n");

    printf("Barcode: ");
    scanf("%lld", &barcode[0]);
    printf("Price: ");
    scanf("%f", &price[0]);
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity[0]);


    for (i = 0;i < 99; i++) {

        printf("Barcode: ");
        scanf("%lld", &barcode[i]);
        if (barcode[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Price: ");
        scanf("%f", &price[i]);
        printf("Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &quantity[i]);

    }
    calculation(barcode, price, quantity, i);
}

int calculation(long long int barcode[], double price[], int quantity[], int i) {

    double totalAmount;
    int j;

    printf("Goods in Stock \n");
    printf("===============\n");

    //j count and display entered value as long as it is less than i

    for (j=0;j<i+1;j++) {

        printf(" %lld, %.2f, %d, %.2f  \n", barcode[j], price[j], quantity[j]);
    }

    //All prices are added for totalamount
    for(j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {

        totalAmount = price[j] + price[j];
    }

    //totalamount is multiplied by quantity for the final price
    for (j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {

        totalAmount = totalAmount * quantity[j];
    }

    printf("Total value goods in stock: %.2f \n", totalAmount);
}
```

The problem is that when I run the program and enter all data the output is not correct. The output is something like this:

```
Grocery Store Inventory
=======================
Barcode: 123
Price: 1.24
Quantity: 4
Barcode: 1234
Price: 2.24
Quantity: 8
Barcode: 12345
Price: 0.40
Quantity: 20
Barcode: 0
Goods in Stock
===============
 1234, 2.24, 8, -0.00
 12345, 0.40, 20, -0.00
 0, -0.00, 0, -0.00
Total value goods in stock: -0.00
```

We enter barcode, price and quantity and when barcode is 0 the program ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("Quantity: ");
scanf("%d", &quantity[0]);

for (i = 1; i < 99; i++) {

    printf("Barcode: ");
    scanf("%lld", &barcode[i]);
```

You read to position 0 and then again, so `i = 1` is correct

```
calculation(barcode, price, quantity, i-1);
```

You end the `for` loop with i on the barcode with 0 value, so the valid value is i-1:

```
 printf(" %lld, %.2f, %d  \n", barcode[j], price[j], quantity[j]);
```

You wanted to print 4 vlaues, but why when you need 3:

```
for( j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {

    totalAmount = totalAmount + (price[j]*quantity[j]);
}
```

Probably you want to multiply amount for the one type of object.

Answer (score 1):

1. "scanf("%f", &price[0])" 
   Price is an array of doubles. You should use %lf with scanf.
2. In the `for` loop you overwrite barcode[0], quantity[0], price[0].
3. In your calculation function, in the first loop you don't need the last %.2f, since you only have three variables. That is the reason you are getting the -0.00.
4. In the second `for` loop in the calculation function, you sum the prices of your products and multiply it by 2.

Then in your third `for` loop, you multiply the totalprice of all products by the quantity of each product. It makes no sense.

You probably wanted to do this:

```
double sum = 0;
```

Put this line in your second `for` loop and delete the third `for` loop:

```
sum += price[j]*quantity[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

`price` is array of `double`. You should use:

```
scanf("%lf", &price[0]);
```

In this line

```
printf(" %lld, %.2f, %d, %.2f  \n", barcode[j], price[j], quantity[j]);
```

you have 4 identifiers, but only 3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have two sets of the three scanf() calls, once for index 0 and then 99 times again, starting with index 0. So the first set of data you enter is always overwritten by the second.